# Highlight relative row in html table when clicking on Highchart data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

So I have a situation similar to this fiddle <strike>http://jsfiddle.net/d15k2nyw/</strike> http://jsfiddle.net/ifix/e0v4g6mx/

Clicking pie graphs should highlight appropriate rows in table, eg clicking Chrome would highlight all users with Chrome, ideally with a colour which is assigned to Chrome part of the pie.

I assume this could be something in a line of

```
click: function(e) {
   $('#' + this.options.id).addClass("highlight");
},
```

but my jQuery is very weak. I can, however, imagine that the class names could be created with a "slugify" function from data quite easily, jQuery being internet citizen from its birth. Oh and btw, my data are in CSV so I cannot do too many smart things with series > data.

Your help highly appreciated.

Comment: where you have tables?

Comment: Apparently I posted a fiddle link with unsaved draft. This is the right one: http://jsfiddle.net/ifix/e0v4g6mx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/d15k2nyw/2/).
What has been added...

First of all, you didn't have any table, so I added one.

Then in order to highlight a row you have to define a css class. I didn't want to deal with css so I added [bootstrap CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/), Bootstrap will highlight the row with its `active` class. In the html, you only have to use the bootstrap class for table:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">|
```

The class attribute is for bootstrap, the ID will help to link the table with your chart.

So far so good, we also need to link each row with its related value. That's why I added in each `tr` an id:

```
 <tr id="Microsoft">
  <td>Microsoft Internet Explorer</td>
  <td>56.33</td>
</tr>
```

Now, our html & css are ready! how to work with them in the chart?
Pretty easy, add an id property with your data:

```
name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable', //The name in your chart
id: 'Proprietary', //The id
y: 0.2 //the value
```

add a click event:

```
events: {
   click: function (event) {
//Our jquery which will highlight the row here
   }
}
```

and a jquery in the click function:

```
$("#myTable tbody tr:not(#" + this.id + ")").removeClass('active');
$("#myTable #" + this.id).toggleClass('active');
```

The important part here is `this`. `this` is the object implicitly given when you clicked on a part of the chart. It has the properties we defined in the serie:

```
 name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable', //The name in your chart
 id: 'Proprietary', //The id
 y: 0.2 //the value
```

The id is accessible in the `this` object. Jquery will use it in order to know which row is related to the clicked data.

The first row will disable the highlight if id not matching the actual clicked data, second row will highlight the matching row.

As a bonus you can also highlight the row with its relative color in the chart.
Just change the `jquery`:

```
 // $("#users tbody tr:not(." + slugify(this.name) + ")").removeClass('active');
 $("#users tbody tr:not(." + slugify(this.name) + ")").css({'background-color': ''})
 // $("#users tbody tr." + slugify(this.name)).toggleClass('active');
 $("#users tbody tr." + slugify(this.name)).css({'background-color': this.id})
Hope it's clear :)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a good start. Apologies for posting wrong fiddle... The situation is a bit more complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/ifix/e0v4g6mx/ The rows cannot be id but class as there's more needed to be highlighted. Also I cannot edit the series data, they come as CSV. But I wonder if the class name can come from "this" - eg if this.name would return the name of the slice, then I could "sluggify" the string (such as "microsoft-internet-explorer") and then use it as class name of rows (which I build with PHP or .NET so no problem adding classes there).

Comment: @JosefHabr, there is something I don't understand.  Even if you data come from csv or whatever, you want to show the html table, so you will have to code it, isn't it?
You only have to add in the html the id (not in the csv). 
You can do it with the name attribute, but a name could have a space, that's why I think an `id` is more appropriate

Comment: You actually pointed me in the very right direction, thank you very much! Please have a look at the final Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ifix/qszhh5er/ - and apologies again for the wrong Fiddle in the first place. No I couldn't use ID's as they have to be unique, but I was able to slugify(this.name) and toggle the appropriate classes.

Comment: @JosefHabr you're welcome. 
Seems your fiddle is working pretty well :).
Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also How does accepting an answer work if you don't know how to do: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B

Comment: I've just done it. A bonus point would be to highlight the table using the same colour as the pie slice. I know how to colour the slices, but I realise I would need both something like this.color and toggleStyle, otherwise my classes would have to be probably named as colours.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/qszhh5er/1/. Just update the jquery. in the click event.
You can see it in my answer

Comment: thank you! I actually tried on my own and found out this.color actually works. Or am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/ifix/qszhh5er/2/